# Cannot change font.name for style "Heading 1"

Tags: python-docx

I'm generating *.docx using python-docx. Cannot change font name for the built-in style "Heading 1". The font is still "Calibri". Other things, including changing of font size and color, work as expected.

```py
import os
from docx import Document


filename = "sample.docx"

doc = Document()
heading_1_style = doc.styles["Heading 1"]
heading_1_style.font.name = "Arial"
doc.add_heading("Heading 1")
doc.save(filename)
os.startfile(filename)
```

The font name of "Heading 1" is still Calibri instead Arial.

Updated: Simplified sample code.

Answer (score 0):

As a start, reproduce the behavior you're seeing with a much simpler script. This will greatly reduce the complexity of the problem:

```
document = Document()
heading_1 = document.styles["Heading 1"]
font = heading_1.font
print("original font size is %s pt" % font.size.pt)
font.size = Pt(18)
print("changed font size is %s pt" % font.size.pt)
document.add_heading("A Level-1 Heading")
document.save("sample.docx")
```

If this works, you have narrowed your problem to the other parts of your code. If not, you have a simpler problem to solve, and in particular, one that others can readily help you with. I recommend you try this, see what you find, and then ask another question if you are still having trouble.

Comment: The problem is old. Found a workaround here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37220754/cant-change-heading-1-font-name-using-docx?rq=1