# How do I change Heading font face and size in python-docx?

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

I filed this as a python-docx issue: https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/805 but was requested to open a discussion here.

https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/styles-using.html implies that I should be able to change Heading font styles like this:

```
font = doc.styles['Heading 1'].font
font.name = 'Times New Roman'
font.size = docx.shared.Pt(16)
```

But that doesn't work: the resulting document uses Calibri for all headings. (They're also blue and Heading 1 has an underline, which I also need to eliminate somehow.)

It also doesn't work to change the font on a specific heading, nor to delete the latent_styles for the headings.

Here's a test program that tries all three methods, but the Headings 1 and 2 still come out as blue Calibri despite all attempts to change them to Times New Roman:

```
import docx

doc = docx.Document()

# Deleting heading latent styles seems to do nothing:
latent_styles = doc.styles.latent_styles
latent_styles['Heading 1'].delete()
latent_styles['Heading 2'].delete()

# Setting the Normal font works:
font = doc.styles['Normal'].font
font.name = 'Times New Roman'
font.size = docx.shared.Pt(12)

# Setting heading styles doesn't do anything:
# they all still end up as blue Calibri.
font = doc.styles['Heading 1'].font
font.name = 'Times New Roman'
font.size = docx.shared.Pt(16)

font = doc.styles['Heading 2'].font
font.name = 'Times New Roman'
font.size = docx.shared.Pt(14)

doc.add_heading("Heading 0", 0)
doc.add_paragraph('Here is a paragraph of text.')
doc.add_heading("Heading 1", 1)
doc.add_paragraph('Here is a paragraph of text.')
doc.add_heading("Heading 2", 2)
doc.add_paragraph('Here is a paragraph of text.')

# It also doesn't work to change the style of a specific heading:
heading = doc.add_heading("Another Heading 1", 1)
heading.style.font.name = "Times New Roman"
doc.add_paragraph('Here is a paragraph of text.')

doc.save('test.docx')
```

[Can't change "heading 1" font name using docx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37220754/cant-change-heading-1-font-name-using-docx) mentions this as a bug, and suggests creating a new style as a workaround. A simpler workaround is to create runs inside normal paragraph text, then style those runs. But it seems like it would be better to use standard elements like "Heading 1" if it was possible to style those headings as something other than blue Calibri ... and the documentation implies this is possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you observe, normally changing the typeface (`font.name`) for a style "just works". For reasons I don't fully understand, the `Title` and perhaps `Heading 1`, `Heading 2`, etc. styles are an exception. I expect this has to do with their font choices being specified by the theme. Perhaps it is related to their special role in forming a table-of-contents.

To start, a couple observations:

- The style applied by `document.add_heading("0th-level Heading", 0)` is `Title`. This makes some sort of sense I suppose, in that the highest-level heading entitles the whole document. The styles `Heading 1`, `Heading 2`, etc. are applied when `1` and `2` are used in that function call, respectively.
- If we apply the font-name "Times New Roman" to the `Title` style and then inspect the XML generated we see the following:

```
>>> heading = document.add_heading("Title", 0)
>>> title_style = heading.style
>>> title_style.font.name = "Times New Roman"
>>> title_style.element.xml
<w:style xmlns:w=... w:type="paragraph" w:styleId="Title">
  <w:name w:val="Title"/>
  <w:basedOn w:val="Normal"/>
  <w:next w:val="Normal"/>
  <w:link w:val="TitleChar"/>
  <w:uiPriority w:val="10"/>
  <w:qFormat/>
  <w:rsid w:val="00FC693F"/>
  <w:pPr>
    <w:pBdr>
      <w:bottom w:val="single" w:sz="8" w:space="4" w:color="4F81BD" w:themeColor="accent1"/>
    </w:pBdr>
    <w:spacing w:after="300" w:line="240" w:lineRule="auto"/>
    <w:contextualSpacing/>
  </w:pPr>
  <w:rPr>
    <w:rFonts w:asciiTheme="majorHAnsi" w:eastAsiaTheme="majorEastAsia"
              w:hAnsiTheme="majorHAnsi" w:cstheme="majorBidi"
              w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman"/>
    <w:color w:val="17365D" w:themeColor="text2" w:themeShade="BF"/>
    <w:spacing w:val="5"/>
    <w:kern w:val="28"/>
    <w:sz w:val="52"/>
    <w:szCs w:val="52"/>
  </w:rPr>
</w:style>
```

- From this we can see a lot if interesting items, but our focus for the moment can be limited to the `<w:rFonts>` element:

```
>>> title_style.element.rPr.rFonts.xml
<w:rFonts w:asciiTheme="majorHAnsi" w:eastAsiaTheme="majorEastAsia"
          w:hAnsiTheme="majorHAnsi" w:cstheme="majorBidi"
          w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman"/>
```

We can see that "Times New Roman" has indeed by applied to two of the font settings, yet the title still appears in Calibri, which as it happens is what "majorHAnsi" maps to.

To jump to the solution, if we set the `w:asciiTheme` font-name to "Times New Roman", the heading appears as desired:

```
from docx.oxml.ns import qn

rFonts = title_style.element.rPr.rFonts
rFonts.set(qn("w:asciiTheme"), "Times New Roman")
```

I expect the same sort of procedure will work on other heading styles.

Note that if you are generating a document from "scratch" rather than editing an existing one, it may be easier to start with a blank document that already has the styles you want:

```
document = Document("my-starting-document.docx")
```

Comment: Thank you! This works. I was also able to change the color to black in a similar way: heading.style.element.rPr.color.set(docx.oxml.ns.qn("w:val"), "000000")

Comment: Glad to hear it :) `from docx.shared import RGBColor; title_style.font.color = RGBColor(0x00, 0x00, 0x00)` should work for the color setting, which would avoid the low-level XML access for that aspect.

Comment: I get "AttributeError: can't set attribute" if I try heading.style.font.color = docx.shared.RGBColor(0x00, 0x00, 0x00)

Comment: Oh, on closer look it's `heading.style.font.color.rgb = RGBColor(0, 0, 0)`; the `.color` attribute on `Font` is a ColorFormat object, not an RGBColor directly.

Comment: Sure enough! That works for me too -- thanks, much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
heading = my_docx.add_heading('', level=1)
run = heading.add_run("my heading")
run.bold = True
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible way to solve this problem, but I don't know how to implement it. If you open the created one .docx as an archive and go to the \word\theme folder, open the file theme1.xml and change the line <a:latin typeface="Calibri"/> to <a:latin typeface="Times New Roman"/> all headers will accept this font. The file theme1.xml located here "\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\docx-template\word\theme\theme 1.xml ". But I don't want to modify it.

Answer (score -1):

It very easy ! Let's ask chatGPT. The answer is shown below:

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Pt
from docx.enum.text import WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT
doc = Document()
def set_heading_style(heading, font_name, font_size):
    run = heading.runs[0]
    font = run.font
    font.name = font_name
    font.size = Pt(font_size)
# Add a main title
title = doc.add_heading('Main Title', level=1)
set_heading_style(title, 'Arial', 18)  # Change 'Arial' and 18 to your desired font and size

# Add a subheading
subheading = doc.add_heading('Subheading', level=2)
set_heading_style(subheading, 'Times New Roman', 14)  # Change 'Times New Roman' and 14 to your desired font and size

# Add more content and headings as needed
doc.save('document_with_custom_headings.docx')
```

Comment: Are you aware of our policy [forbidding AI-generated answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/354577)?